# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute en un programa para contar nodos de forma recursiva en un Arbol B

Tags: python-3.x, árboles-binarios

Intentando hacer un procedimiento de conteo de nodos de un Árbol B en un programa en Python me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
return 1 + self.HijoIzq().NumeroNodosRec() + self.HijoDer.NumeroNodosRec() 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'NumeroNodosRec'
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
class ArbolB:
    def __init__(self,objRaiz):
        self.key = objRaiz
        self.izq = None
        self.der = None

        
    def insertarIzq(self,Nodo):
        if self.izq == None:
            self.der = ArbolB(Nodo)
        else:
            t = ArbolB(Nodo)
            t.izq = self.izq
            self.izq = t

    def insertarDer(self,Nodo):
        if self.der == None:
            self.der = ArbolB(Nodo)
        else:
            t = ArbolB(Nodo)
            t.der = self.der
            self.der = t

    def HijoDer(self):
        return self.der

    def HijoIzq(self):
        return self.izq

    def setValRaizl(self,obj):
        self.key = obj

    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.key        

    def NumeroNodosRec(self):
        if self == None:
            return 0
        elif self.izq == None and self.der == None:
            return 1
        else:
            return 1 +  self.HijoIzq().NumeroNodosRec() + self.HijoDer.NumeroNodosRec()


def main():
    r = ArbolB('a')
    r.insertarIzq('b')
    r.insertarDer('c')
    r.insertarIzq('d')
    r.insertarDer('e')
    print(r.NumeroNodosRec())        

main()
```

¿Alguna idea de como corregirlo?

Answer (score 0):

Mira con atención

Error 1:

```
def insertarIzq(self,Nodo):
    if self.izq == None:
        self.der = ArbolB(Nodo)
```

Error 2:

```
return 1 +  self.HijoIzq().NumeroNodosRec() + self.HijoDer.NumeroNodosRec()
```

Error 3:

Suponer que **todo** nodo tiene izq y der != `None`.

**Código correcto**

```
class ArbolB:
    def __init__(self, objRaiz):
        self.key = objRaiz
        self.izq = None
        self.der = None

    def insertarIzq(self, Nodo):
        if self.izq == None:
            self.izq = ArbolB(Nodo)
        else:
            t = ArbolB(Nodo)
            t.izq = self.izq
            self.izq = t

    def insertarDer(self, Nodo):
        if self.der == None:
            self.der = ArbolB(Nodo)
        else:
            t = ArbolB(Nodo)
            t.der = self.der
            self.der = t

    def HijoDer(self):
        return self.der

    def HijoIzq(self):
        return self.izq

    def setValRaizl(self, obj):
        self.key = obj

    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.key

    def NumeroNodosRec(self):
        if self == None:
            return 0
        elif self.izq == None and self.der == None:
            return 1
        else:
            suma = 1
            if self.HijoIzq():
                suma += self.HijoIzq().NumeroNodosRec()
            if self.HijoDer():
                suma += self.HijoDer().NumeroNodosRec()
            #return 1 + self.HijoIzq().NumeroNodosRec() + self.HijoDer.NumeroNodosRec()
            return suma


def main():
    r = ArbolB('a')
    r.insertarIzq('b')
    r.insertarDer('c')
    r.insertarIzq('d')
    r.insertarDer('e')
    print(r.NumeroNodosRec())


main()
```

Comment: Si un nodo tiene hijo izquierdo pero no hijo derecho,¿no debería devolver 0?

Comment: @kktua222 No lo sé. No revise si el código opera correctamente como árbol binario; simplemente identifique la causa del error denunciado y cómo corregirlo.